# How to force intelliJ to import a maven dependency with classifier as a "Maven Library" instead of "Intellij Module"

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

In my maven based IntelliJ project I have 2 modules - modules A and B.

- The pom.xml of module A creates an uber jar (including dependencies which are not accessible by the project) and attaches it as an artifact with classifier "withdeps"
- The pom.xml of module B has a dependency on the classified "withdeps" artifact A

When I import the maven modules IntelliJ adds the module's A source code in the dependencies of module B (ignoring the "withdeps" classifier).

Is it possible to force Intellij to add the module A dependency to B as "maven library" instead of the default "project source code/Intellij module"? If not what can I do to resolve the compilation errors in IntelliJ (Ctrl+F9)

Thanks

Comment: Hey, did you figure out a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the pom.xml of module B only when creating the intellij project. Then all dependencies will be as maven dependencies.

The downside is that this way you will have to open module A as separate project in another window, then when you change something you will have to do mvn install and refresh project B.

Much better solution would be to install all depencencies into maven repository, described [here in maven docs](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html).

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by "installing all dependencies into maven repository"? All dependencies are already in my local repository. The problem is that intelliJ doesn't include them in the "*.iml" files so intelliJ compilation (Ctrl+F9) fails. I could add the "withdeps" artifact manually to the module B classpath (module settings) but I want to automate the process and avoid extra steps

Comment: Then you probably need to enable "Import Maven projects automatically" in maven settings. See https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/maven-importing.html

Comment: Not ideal solution but it works - I have removed the maven module which creates the classified artifacts so IntelliJ was forced to use the maven library instead of the IntelliJ module!